# How to calculate the txHash?

Tags: transactions

When i have a rawTx ,such as this '15e2d20fae45d0c19a01177b48c79f1298a3343b2f4a4286ec27b7bdca0ae8cb070000e7fb71f07fb0a5ac3ec398f6ad47c10730d2145ff309bcdd04f855ac0200cc5febf12dc07f8e71b6f73d485ea733a77c3908d1b4e9bb0582579edb762756080000e7fb71f07fb0a5ac3ec398f6ad47c10730d2145ff309bddd04f855ac02e09143000056a48224cb245a4ede4774d377e94fd01d0a7eefff00000002030b35676fe47e2d12a184e7693640e8ab6ac1d3fa640b5da03ea1b9d1649e55383f6e58a330602fdc1f5dd028b4e0e948e1cbc78565a70027cfcb2d6a955412010d'
how to get the txHash?

Answer (score 5):

1. Create a 32 byte generic hash of the raw tx
2. Base58 encode it with the 'o' prefix

It would look something like this:

```
var rawHash = libsodium.crypto_generichash(32, rawTx);
var prefix = new Uint8Array([5, 116]); // 'o'
var merged = new Uint8Array(prefix.length + rawHash.length);
merged = merged.set(prefix);
merged = merged.set(rawHash, prefix.length);
var txHash = Bs58check.encode(merged);
```

Comment: Thanks, it's solve my problem

Comment: @ruanqunfeng please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark when you are satisfied with the answer, tx!

Comment: This answer should include the actual result: Which txid/txHash does this raw hex *actually* match?

Comment: Input (Carthagenet): "f711fa7cad51cf5c426b3d12c43e342374be29a2529241f823b8ae313bbcc0af6c000786cf9445307bd5092ebdccc891298c086676c58b0aedef64af5000c0e7fb0a0000ffc412ec694ac31e3a3af70433139129096577d000384978f679098ea5400da89879e1cd0061ba3df5ecdd7d3597d001db9fdb8dae190a943b8b55f48b57eda21b232b58b162962694ac62797e5d35ef8e7385100e"
Result: "oo9tuhqPwjUZLPRcCmNrmUHECCMBMpdarbax11Ar5tzs5yiJCAJ"

Comment: This is what you're hashing:
http://doc.tzalpha.net/api/p2p.html#operation-shell

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately I can't vote up again but I think that this result should be contained in the answer.