# How to get raw transaction from Tezos node

Tags: node, tezos-client, transactions

Given an operation ID, I would like the raw transaction as it appears on the blockchain, as a hex string. can I get the raw transaction from the Tezos node or Tezos CLI? How?

Comment: I am referring to the same format of the transaction as is discussed here: https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/2572/how-to-decode-raw-transaction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to know what level (block height) to look at based on the provided operation hash (operation id). You have public indexer API's like [tzkt](https://api.tzkt.io/#operation/Operations_GetByHash) or [tzstats](https://tzstats.com/docs/api#operations) that can make this very easy for you. Then you can [get](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/172/how-can-i-understand-why-a-transaction-has-failed/177#177) the parsed operation(s) directly from the RPC API. After that you can forge it locally with for example [Taquito](https://github.com/ecadlabs/taquito/tree/master/packages/taquito-local-forging) to get it as a hex string. Lastly, you can [calculate the operation hash](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1442/how-to-calculate-the-txhash) from the op bytes if you need to verify that the responses from indexer API and RPC API were correct/honest.

Comment: This is a great answer. But it would be a lot simpler and nicer if I could just get the unparsed transaction hex directly from the node. I guess it has it in memory since it can provide a parsed version of the transaction, so it shouldn't be too hard to add it as a field in the response.

Comment: Also: Not all libraries are good enough to be able to do this. Sure Taquito is excellent, but the Java library, especially, and the C# probably can't do this.

Comment: You can also forge it remotely (http://doc.tzalpha.net/api/rpc.html#post-block-id-helpers-forge-operations). That would be equivalent to getting the raw hex directly from the node.

Comment: Am I wrong about it being easy to add to the node, though?

Comment: The hash verification is a good point, though. Then you dont have to trust the response.

Comment: Can't be hard to add something like that to the node. But I suspect no one have requested that feature before.

Comment: Added this as a feature request for the Tezos node
https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/issues/934
please vote up :)

Comment: Will approve as answer once/if I get this working